# Placing the labels in a plot along the x-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, label

I made a plot in R and now i want to place the labels along the x-axis of the plot. I want to place the labels in the center of the number of samples that belong to a particular population. If I have 5 populations with sample size 10, 20,20,35,100 then label should be at 10/2 for population 1, 20/2 for population 2 and so on. I tried the following but it doesnt work. Ill appreciate any further help!
sample of my input file (input.5.Q, showing only 5 samples.In real it consists of 185 rows and 5 columns)

```
1   0.364957    0.00001 1.00E-05    0.00001 1.00E-05
2   0.485423    0.017426    1.00E-05    0.00001 1.00E-05
3   0.399289    0.00001 1.00E-05    0.002894    1.00E-05
4   0.579652    0.00001 1.00E-05    0.00001 1.00E-05
5   0.578574    0.00001 1.00E-05    0.00001 1.00E-05
6   0.597478    0.00001 1.00E-05    0.00001 1.00E-05

tbl<-read.table(input.5.Q)    
pop<-c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", "pop4", "pop5")
    n<-c(10, 20,20,35,100)
    at <- n/2
    barplot(t(as.matrix(tbl)),col=rainbow(5),width=1,space=1)
    mtext(1,at=at,text=pop,cex=1, las=2)
    for{....
    }
```

Comment: I am reading the output from the admixture software into tbl as                tbl <-read.table(test.5.Q)

Comment: Added the sample of input file in  the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
tbl <- read.table("clipboard", row.names= NULL) # read your data
head(tbl)
V1       V2       V3    V4       V5    V6
1  1 0.364957 0.000010 1e-05 0.000010 1e-05
2  2 0.485423 0.017426 1e-05 0.000010 1e-05
3  3 0.399289 0.000010 1e-05 0.002894 1e-05
4  4 0.579652 0.000010 1e-05 0.000010 1e-05
5  5 0.578574 0.000010 1e-05 0.000010 1e-05
6  6 0.597478 0.000010 1e-05 0.000010 1e-05
# the barplot
colnames(tbl)[-1] <-c("pop1", "pop2", "pop3", "pop4", "pop5")
barplot(as.matrix(tbl[,-1]),beside = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jimbou! But thats not what i'm looking for. In my input file first 10 samples belong to pop1, next 20 to pop2 and so on. I want all samples of pop1 together (10 vertical bars) and then to place the label in between somewhere to identify that these 10 samples belong to pop1 and likewise for other pop's too. I got the plot but placing the labels is hard and thats the help i'm looking for. Looking for something like this http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article/figure/image?size=medium&id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pgen.1004254.g006

Comment: @akang Upon your comment I changed my answer. I hop this works now, otherwise please edit your question and make your data reproducible. It's not clear how you plot your barplot.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, try something like this (it's not exactly what you wanted, but maybe close enough?):

```
# example data
tbl <- data.frame(population = c(rep("pop1", 10), rep(c("pop2", "pop3"), each = 20), rep("pop4", 35), rep("pop5", 100)), 
              V1 = seq(0, 1, size = 185, replace = TRUE),
              V2 = seq(0, 0.1, size = 185, replace = TRUE),
              V3 = seq(1e-05, 0, size = 185, replace = TRUE),
              V4 = seq(0, 0.01, size = 185, replace = TRUE),
              V5 = seq(1e-05, 0, size = 185, replace = TRUE))


library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
```

I created a function for the plots, to make it easier to plot each variable individually. I also tried putting all variables into one plot but this came out not very nice - too messy

```
plot_func <- function(column){
  ggplot(data = tbl, aes_string(x = 1:nrow(tbl), y = column, fill = "population")) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.position = "bottom")
}

# run the plot function for each variable and plot
for (i in 2:ncol(tbl)){
  assign(paste("p", i-1, sep = ""), plot_func(column = paste0(colnames(tbl)[i])))
}

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, ncol=2)
```

[image]